# What would be an appropriate data-structure to store a 2D table structure in memory?

Tags: java, data-structures, store, in-memory

I have a 2D table structure that I am reading from an underlying database, and I am wondering, what is the best in-memory data-structure to use to store it into. 
Where, it can be accessible for further reading, manipulation, etc.

Comment: You haven't defined what manipulation you need to do so its hard to give a solution. Do you need to access the data in the order it was returned from the database, then you would store the rows in a List. If that doesn't matter then you could use a Map. Is all the data simply strings, then you might just store each row in a List. If the data is different and you need to peform other processing on the data, then you should probably create a bean so you can access the data properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do maps of maps something like

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> table = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();
```

Here is an example

```
column_a(primary),  column_b,  column_c
--------------------------------
abc              |  xyz      | 123
def              |  xxx      | 456
```

So after you read the table you use it like this:

```
map.get("abc").get("column_b").equals("xyz")
map.get("def").get("column_c").equals("456")
```

Hope this helps. 
Note: I chose the first map to have a key of string because your table may not have integers as IDs. You can change them if you think Integer would fit better.

Comment: Could you explain this model? I was thinking:
Map<String, List<String>>
such that: column names map to a list of string column data
please explain your model? thnx

Comment: It a map that holds other maps. It like a 2d array except its 2d map. I am not sure what else to explain than that you should probably try it.

Comment: but could you explain the semantics of it, like what is the key of the first map meant to refer to? what is the key of the second map meant to refer to? what is the value of the second map meant to refer to? apart from that I can visualise it, but am interested to know it what way you are recommending to use it.. thnx again

Comment: Yes thanks.. But actually my particular table doesn’t have a primary key, it just contains columns and data?!

Comment: I think you can use above to do something similar. Instead of using a Map, try a list of Map like List<Map<String, String>>. I am not going to show an example of that because its basically the same. Good luck! And don't forget to accept a correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

Guava libraries has two different implementations for the [Table](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) interface: `HashBasedTable` and `TreeBasedTable`. You should take a look.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, things like this are often *code smell*. You might want to consider creating a bean that represents a row on a table and using `List<MyBean>` instead of some generic table horror.

Of course this assumes you know what the table looks like beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

An array of hashmaps keyed column name => value makes sense to me.